# como consultar 2 diferentes resultados en un misma columna?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estoy intentando realizar una consulta, en donde en una misma columna tengo dos diferentes estados, les explico

columna = estados
estado 1
estado 2

mi código para

```
$auc = "SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE estados=1";
    $au_count = $conexion->query($auc);
    while( $count_row = $au_count->fetch_array() )
    { 


        $pubAsig=$count_row['estados'];



    }
```

Lo que quiero lograr aquí es mostrar tanto el resultado 1 como el resultado 2 en la misma consulta, pero ambos están en la misma columna y no logro ubicarlos.

Comment: Solo para confirmar: ¿Actualmente tienes los dos valores en una misma columna, por ejemplo un nombre y un apellido en una columna 'nombre completo'?

Comment: si es correcto, en una misma columna, pero no en una misma fila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM resultados WHERE estados=1 OR estados=2";
$au_count = $conexion->query($sql);

while ($count_row = $au_count->fetch_array()) { 

    // Mostrar aquí los campos necesarios.  

}
```

Comment: gracias Muriano este quedo perfecto